# Static functions in an assembly to be used in a web application. Getting Attempted to read or write protected memory error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, assembly, dll, .net-assembly

I have an `assembly(dll)` which is pre complied and i have no idea who built it and have no access to the source code yet.

Now this `assembly(dll)` is used in a Windows Application.

Currently we are working on a project where we want to covert the assembly part of the functionality to be made available in a Web Application.

However, the functions used in the assembly are Shared Functions and do not support multi-threading which will fail in the Web Application.

How can i use this `assembly(.dll)` in a Web Application.?
Is there a work around to accomplish this?

Will creating a class and moving the function used in the assembly to a function in the new class and using the instance of this class resolve the issue?

`The assembly in question converts the dxf images to emf files.`

I created a multi threading environment within my windows application and the dll crashes.
It gives the following error.

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Comment: Do the static functions hold some internal state? I'd like to understand why the methods would not be suitable in a web application. Functions that hold internal state don't sound like good candidates to be made static. You could inspect the source code of the assembly using something like Reflector, ILSpy, DotPeek or similar.

Comment: @RussCam...well what i did today was to create a multi threading environment within my windows application and it fails. it gives this error..."Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt"